# Any Gem that helps to get the http status of the specified URL in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, url, rubygems

There are number of URLs that I want to test and want to know the HTTP status of each of these URLs without hitting them in browser.

does anyone has idea about the gem, which can help me to find the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you could achieve this with standard ruby (`Net::HTTP` and friends). However there are many gems to handle stuff like that. I have a bias towards [Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus).

Example :

```
Typhoeus::Request.get('http://google.fr').code
=> 301
```

Answer (score 2):

How about standard Ruby, no extra gems (just `require 'net/http'`):

```
Net::HTTP.new('google.com').head('/').code
#=> "301"
```

If for some reason you want to do more than a head request, replace `head` with `get`.

Answer (score 0):

use [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty):

```
uri = "http://url.to.inspect"

request = HTTParty.get( uri )
return true if request.code.to_i == 200
```